# Loading Javascript file within component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Hi I have gone through some answers but none of them seem to work. I have a Javascript file like so.  It is stored in my src folder.

```
let model = function() {

    let model = function(data) {
        if (!data) return;
        return map.call(this, data);
    };

    function map(data) {
        return data;
    }

    model.map = function(_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return map;
        map = _;
        return model;
    };

    return model;

};
```

In one of my components, I am trying to use this file.

```
import model from '../models/GraphModel';
```

And then I am trying to use it.

```
var graph = model();
console.log(graph);
```

But nothing seems to output and I cant seem to set anything.  How can I use this Javascript in my components?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

I think it's because you didn't export `model`.

Try adding `export` before `let`: `export let model`.

And import it as such: `import { model } from '../models/GraphModel';`